# GIMP on Linux Mint opens but does not work

Tags: linux-mint, freeze, gimp

In Linux Mint, the Gimp installed by the "Software Manager" opens but does not work. When you are going to paint something, the brush freezes, as shown in image below. The brush does not accompany the mouse pointer and is frozen at the screen edge. You can select the tools, but you can't paint. When the operating system was installed and Gimp was installed soon after, it did not give a problem, so it must be a conflict with another program.

[image]

Comment: Virtual machine or real?

Comment: @roaima real machine

Answer (score 0):

Install using snap instead "Software Manager"

```
sudo snap install gimp
```